# How can I Select Distinct values with multiple columns and tables in SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

How can I Select Distinct values with multiple columns and tables in SQL server?

Here is my code:

```
SELECT registryno,registrystatus,psPatRegisters.pattrantype,PK_psPatRegisters,
       payername,*
FROM psPatRegisters,psPatinv
WHERE psPatRegisters.PK_psPatRegisters=psPatinv.FK_psPatRegisters
    AND registryno between '7133' and '7169'
    AND psPatinv.pattrantype='I'
GROUP BY psPatRegisters.PK_psPatRegisters
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Why you need to use * ? It will select all the columns.

Comment: Perhaps you could give us a sample of the output you are expecting

Answer (score 2):

remove the "group by" and "*" and use distinct. Or you have to group by all the selected fields (without *) at that time distinct is not required

Answer (score 0):

Would that work for you?

```
select distinct egistryno,registrystatus,
       psPatRegisters.pattrantype,PK_psPatRegisters,payername
from psPatRegisters,psPatinv
where psPatRegisters.PK_psPatRegisters=psPatinv.FK_psPatRegisters
and registryno between '7133' and '7169'
and psPatinv.pattrantype='I'
```

Also, you cannot group and select columns that are not in the grouping clause without aggregate functions.

Answer (score 0):

All Columns in Projection most be in Group By .

```
SELECT  registryno ,
    registrystatus ,
    psPatRegisters.pattrantype ,
    PK_psPatRegisters ,
    payername
FROM    psPatRegisters ,
    psPatinv
WHERE   psPatRegisters.PK_psPatRegisters = psPatinv.FK_psPatRegisters
    AND registryno BETWEEN '7133' AND '7169'
    AND psPatinv.pattrantype = 'I'
GROUP BY registryno ,
    registrystatus ,
    psPatRegisters.pattrantype ,
    PK_psPatRegisters ,
    payername
```

Or Use `DISTINCT` KeyWord

```
SELECT  
DISTINCT
    registryno ,
    registrystatus ,
    psPatRegisters.pattrantype ,
    PK_psPatRegisters ,
    payername
FROM    psPatRegisters ,
    psPatinv
WHERE   psPatRegisters.PK_psPatRegisters = psPatinv.FK_psPatRegisters
    AND registryno BETWEEN '7133' AND '7169'
    AND psPatinv.pattrantype = 'I'
```

and i think if you want only delete duplicate value from your result , best way is use `DISTINCT`
but if you want use aggregate function (Like Sum/Min/...) you most use `Group By`